# PROBLEMA CON BARRA DE NAVEGACION

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con mi barra de navegacion, estoy haciendo un sistema de pago de condominio, donde el apartado del administrador y el apartado del usuario son diferentes, pero ambos tienen barra de navegacion, presento dos problemas, el primero es:

1- estoy utilizando bootstrap para hacer la maquetacion mas rapido, en el inicio del apartado del administrador y el apartado del usuario me carga boostrap bien, pero cuando le doy a un enlace, en las otras paginas no entiendo porque, pero no me carga boostrap.

2- el segundo problema que tengo es, que cuando estoy en el apartado principal de administrador o de usuario y me dirijo a un enlace lo carga, pero luego cuando quiero navegar a otro enlace me dice error 404, y no entiendo porque, si puse las direcciones bien.
Adjunto codigo.

APARTADO DE ADMINISTRADOR
EN ESE APARTADO APARECE BOOTSTRAP CON NORMALIDAD

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="e">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Bienvenido Administrador</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require 'admin/function.admin.php'
    ?>
    <header>
<a href="<?php echo RUTA.'close.php' ?>">Cerrar Sesion</a>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h6>Bienvenido <?php echo $user['usuario']; ?></h6></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="views/admin.view.php">Ingresar Facturas<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="views/admin.pagos.php">Ver Pagos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="views/admin.condominio.php">Calcular Condominio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo RUTA.'close.php' ?>">Cerrar Sesion</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
</nav>
</header>
    <form method="POST" action="">
       <h1>Factura</h1>
<br> <hr>
        <h3>Concepto</h3>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo">
<br> <hr>

        <h3>Descripcion del Pago</h3>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion">
<br> <hr>

        <h3>Costo</h3>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="costo" placeholder="Costo">
<br> <hr>

<h3>Reportar Pago en Divisas</h3>


<input class="form-control" type="number" name="divisas" placeholder="Divisas">
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="bolivares" placeholder="Costo en Bs.S">
<button type="submit" value="multiplicar" name="calcular" class="btn btn-primary">Calcular</button>
<input type="text" name="resultado" readonly value="<?php echo number_format($calcular,2,".",",")?>">

<br> <hr>

    <h3>Numero de Factura o Referencia</h3>
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="factura" placeholder="Factura o Referencia">
<br> <hr>

<h3>Fecha de Pago</h3>
<input type="date" name="fecha">
<br> <hr>

<h3>Subir Imagenes</h3>
<div class="custom-file">
<input type="file" name="imagen" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
<label class="custom-file-label" name="imagen" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
    </div>
    <br> <hr>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="generar">Generar Factura</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

EN ESTE APARTADO YA NO ME APARACE BOOTSTRAP Y TENGO EL PROBLEMA CON LOS ENLACES

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<title>Ver Pagos</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<a href="<?php echo RUTA.'close.php' ?>">Cerrar Sesion</a>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">     
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="views/admin.view.php">Ingresar Facturas<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="views/admin.pagos.php">Ver Pagos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="views/admin.condominio.php">Calcular Condominio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo RUTA.'close.php' ?>">Cerrar Sesion</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
</nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTA: no me arroja ningun error de sintaxis o que no he definido una variable, el backend esta escrito en php y todo hasta los momentos va bien, el problema es con HTML y CSS se podria decir, de antemano muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el atributo href en tu link a bootstrap, debería ir el "/" al inicio. Tu url debería quedar de esta manera

```
"/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

una manera de verificar si esta cargando bien el css es:

ingresar desde el navegador > click derecho > inspeccionar > seleccionar la pestaña "Network" o "Red" y recargar, si aparece en rojo es porque el enlace esta apuntando mal.

Comment: Hice el cambio que me sugeriste y de igual manera no detecta el boostrap. Busque en en el apartado de inspeccionar y en red me salia boostrap con error 404 como si lo buscara y no apareciera, lo cual es muy raro, porque en el primero codigo, en el apartado principal de administrador si me carga bien bootstrap

Comment: ¿Porqué debería ir el "/" al inicio?

Comment: porque me imagino que la pagina principal y el css estan en la raiz, algo como esto:

`/index.php`
`/views/admin.view.php`
`/views/admin.pagos.php`
`/css/bootstrap.css`


entonces si entra al admin que esta dentro del directorio views al no tener el `"/"` va a ir a buscar el css a: `"/view/css/bootstrap.css"`

Comment: Solucionado el problema, el enlace que estaba poniendo estaba mal, ya corregi el error. Muchisismas gracias!